# Identifier expected in a xaml ResourceDictionary for theming purpose in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created two xamls (I created as ContentPage) one for Light theme and another for Dark theme (for iOS)

The LightTheme.xaml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="LightTheme"/>
```

and LightTheme.xaml.cs

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace MyApp.Forms
{
  [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
  public partial class LightTheme : ResourceDictionary
  {
  }
}
```

Similar for DarkTheme.xaml(.cs).

In App.xaml.cs I put

```
public static void ApplyTheme()
{
  if (AppInfo.RequestedTheme == AppTheme.Dark)
  {
    App.Current.Resources = new DarkTheme();
  }
  else
  {
    App.Current.Resources = new LightTheme();
  }
}
```

and App.xaml

```
...
<ResourceDictionary Source="LightTheme.xaml">
  <local:AppResource x:Key="AppResource"></local:AppResource>

  <OnPlatform x:Key="validMargin" x:TypeArguments="Thickness"  >
    <On Platform="UWP" Value="0,-5,0,0"/>
  </OnPlatform>


  <!--The Colors-->
  <Color x:Key="DarkPrimary">#403152</Color>
  <Color x:Key="Primary">#564266</Color>

 ...
```

When build solution, I got errors

[image]

How to fix it ?

Comment: The error happened inside Theme.xaml , please post the code in the two theme.xaml .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the scheme `x:Class` in LightTheme.xaml , it should be namespace + class name ,modify as below

```
x:Class="Namespace.LightTheme"
```